# JSON.stringify() not converting to string when posting to MVC action

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

This code is being used to send `id` of an anchor element on its click event from a view to a controller using ajax and jQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('click', 'a', function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("/brandsOfACategory")',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset:utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify(this.id)
        })
    });
</script>
```

Action Method used to catch this string is:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult brandsOfACategory(string id)
{
    return View();
}
```

But `string id` in this action method is coming as null. I checked Network tab of Chrome developer tool for Request Payload to check the value of the parameter and it is an object and not a string. It's screen is uploaded here:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/hE240.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you trying to send `id` from ajax call to controller method then you need to pass it as `{key: value}` pair

So instead of this

```
data: JSON.stringify(this.id)
```

Try this

```
data: JSON.stringify({id: this.id})
```